# Extract holidays from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with dates as an index and values as the first column.
I want to take all of the Belgian holidays out of that dataframe and create a new dataframe.

Things I've tried:

```
be_holidays = holidays.BE()

#example of the data frame (same format)
index = pd.date_range(start='08/08/2018',end='08/09/2018',freq='1H')
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,5,3,5,4,6,2,4,6,6,3,2,5,9,7,8,8,5,1,2,5,3,6],columns=['A'], index = index)


new_df = df.applymap(lambda x: str(df.index[x]).split()[0] in be_holidays)

new_df = df[~(str(df.index).split()[0]).isin(be_holidays)]

#for context 
type(df.index[0])
#results is 
pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp
```

Comment: Post sample data in the dataframe

Comment: when you say Belgian holidays are they periodic? Like every third Sunday or something. Else you would need the calendar data. Try this https://pypi.org/project/holidays/ then use a filter function to remove all the occurrences of these dates

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
import pandas as pd

# index must be a datetime
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# boolean mask, to identify holidays
mask = df.index.isin( set(be_holidays) )

# drop holidays, keep rest (~ is `not`)
df = df.loc[~mask]
```